# Constraints in route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

So I have ASP.NET MVC application. I would like to configure its routes. Here is my RouteConfig's code:

```
public static void Register(RouteCollection routes, bool useAttributes = true)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");    

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

This route works fine. Besides I have an area in my application and try to configure its routes too. It is my area registration code:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    try
    {                                                           
        context.MapRoute(
            name: "SiteSettings_Controller",
            url: "SiteSettings/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional,
            // here I tried to use @"(UserManagement|Tools|Settings)" 
            //as constraint but it takes no effect
            constraints: new {controller = "UserManagement|Tools|Settings" }
        );                              
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // here I get InvalidOperationException ""
    }        
}
```

I would like to restrict controllers in SiteSettingsArea's route but when I go to "localhost/SiteSettings/UserManagement" url I get InvalidOperationException with message "No route in the route table matches the supplied values". I believe that this url corresponds to SiteSettings_Controller route but obviously I am wrong. How could I limit controllers in the route properly?

Answer (score 1):

If you search your codebase for `SiteSettings_Controller` does it appear anywhere else?

The below code certainly worked for me when I just tested it.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Areas.SiteSettings
{
    public class SiteSettingsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "SiteSettings";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                name: "SiteSettings_Controller",
                url: "SiteSettings/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    action = "Index",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional
                },
            constraints: new { controller = "UserManagement|Tools|Settings" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```